# jQuery Select only the last class from one element

Tags: jquery

I have elements with clas="a 1" and "a 2", etc. I want to select the last class. For example in "a 1", select 1 and make it 2. How could I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove class and add required:

```
$('.a.1').removeClass('1').addClass('2');
```

Comment: But I want to get the last class in a variable

Comment: You mean like `any last class in list`?

Comment: Yeah. I think I just got it. I used `var lastClass = $('div').attr('class').split(' ').pop();`